# Arduino clone without boot loader and no other Arduino device

Tags: arduino, clone, arduino-uno, bootloader

i recently bought a IEIK Uno clone and it didn't come with a boot loader and i keep getting the error avrdude.exe: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00, iv'e read up a bit and everyone is saying to use another arduino board to burn the boot loader, but i don't have another, is there another way?

Comment: No, you have to use either another Arduino board or an [external programmer](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.TRS0&_nkw=atmel+isp+programmer&_sacat=0).

Comment: And, if I were you, I'd ask the seller to send me another one, since the one without bootloader is unusable as an arduino, and thus the product you received is not compliant with the listing (unless he explicitely said it was without bootloader)

Comment: Are you shure the board doesn't have bootloader? Maybe it has ch340 USB-to-serial converter and need install drivers.